# How can I filter a dict list with subset of a dict?

Tags: python, dictionary, subset

I am trying to find all dicts that include my prepared dict as a subset. I have a dict with 2 keys and I have 5 dicts in a list. I am trying to filter all dicts which includes my dict like this:

```
my_dict = {'A':'A','B':'B'}

all_dict = [{'A':'A','B':'B','C':'C'},{'A':'A','B':'B','C':'C','D':'D'},{'D':'D','E':'E'},{'A':'A','B':'B'},{'A':'A','D':'D'}]

result = []
for i in all_dict:
    if my_dict in i:
       result.append(i)

print(result)

#print output empty list

#output supposed to:
#{'A': 'A', 'B': 'B', 'C': 'C'}
#{'A': 'A', 'B': 'B', 'C': 'C', 'D': 'D'}
#{'A': 'A', 'B': 'B'}
```

According to my for loop, it appends if the dict exactly the same with iteration. How can I find all dicts include my_dict as a subset? What is your suggestions?

Comment: It is kinda confusing what you want to achieve. You just copied all_dict to result and printed the list. Also, what is special about the output? All elements are printed in separate line. Is that what you want to do?

Comment: I don't know how to return true if my_dict is a subset of i. I couldn't figure out what is the method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the fact that `dict.items()` returns a set-like object that can be compared like so:

```
result = [x for x in all_dict if my_dict.items() <= x.items()]
```

Comment: issubset method works to but this one make more sense. Thank you.

Comment: @Murat: `<=` does exactly the same thing as `issubset()` (per the [`set` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.issubset)).

Comment: @martineau because I have almost 2gb of data to filter I will try both. Thank you.

Comment: @Murat: How does that have any bearing on `<=` vs `issubset()`?

Answer (score 3):

You can use list-comprehension, for each dictionary in the list, see if the my_dict's keys is the `subset` of the dictionary's key:

```py
[each for each in all_dict if set(my_dict).issubset(each)]

#output:
[{'A': 'A', 'B': 'B', 'C': 'C'}, {'A': 'A', 'B': 'B', 'C': 'C', 'D': 'D'}, {'A': 'A', 'B': 'B'}]
```

Comment: I couldn't find the issubset method finnaly thank you so much. That was all I want

Comment: It's available only for `sets`

Comment: Oh because of that I couldn't find out. Thank you so much. This is a really easy one.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a function that tests whether a dictionary `dict_1` is a subset of `dict_2`:

```py
def is_subset(dict_1, dict_2):
    for k, v in dict_1.items():
        if k not in dict_2 or dict_2[k]!=v:
            return False
    return True
```

Your code then becomes:

```py
my_dict = {'A':'A','B':'B'}

all_dict = [{'A':'A','B':'B','C':'C'},{'A':'A','B':'B','C':'C','D':'D'},{'D':'D','E':'E'},{'A':'A','B':'B'},{'A':'A','D':'D'}]

result = []
for i in all_dict:
    if is_subset(my_dict, i):
        result.append(i)

print(result)
```

Comment: I know this method but I have almost 20 keys in my_dict

Comment: I may be missing something, but I don't understand why that is a problem. Could you please clarify?

Answer (score 1):

Example without `issubset()`.

Try using `all()`

```
result = [i for i in all_dict if all(grp in i.items() for grp in my_dict.items())]
```